# Как создать массив данных с дельтой?

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

Есть конечный массив `arr` в котором лежат 3 массива всегда равной длины

Как создать массив, в котором будет лежать разница между числами?

Например, если сейчас `a = [3, 1, 5, 7, 6, 7, 8, 10, 3, 3]`,

то в итоге в `arr[0]` должно быть `[-2,4,2,-1,1,1,2,-7,0]`

Может в `numpy` есть какой-то простой способ сделать это одной строчкой или какой-то другой оригинальный способ ?
Данных может быть много и скорость вычислений очень важна.

```
import numpy as np
......
 
a = [3, 1, 5, 7, 6, 7, 8, 10, 3, 3]
b = [11, 15, 17, 86, 11, 67, 31, 56, 3, 11]
c = [12.1, 98.2, 31.6, 24.7, 12.1, 34.1, 1.8, 65.1, 22.9, 31.6]
 
arr = np.array([a, b, c])
 
 
arr_delta = arr ?
```

Comment: быстрее линейного прохода по парам элементов списка с вычислением разницы вряд ли что-то будет...

Comment: а почему -2? если первые числа 3, 11, 12

Comment: @DaniilLoban откуда вы взяли эти числа? см. внимательнее пример, я же написал arr[0] , т.е. рассматриваю только этот подсписок с числами, которые в примере

Comment: я не понял как получается [-2,4,2,-1,1,1,2,0] разница каких чисел 3, 11, 12 - первые числа трех массивов -2 тоже первая

Comment: @DaniilLoban разница между двумя соседними числами

Comment: теперь понял, я бы попробовал сдвинуть копию массива и посчитать разницу

Comment: но у меня вышло таким способом вышло [-2  4  2 -1  1  1  2 -7  0]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возможно, вам нужно это?:

```
import numpy as np

a = [3, 1, 5, 7, 6, 7, 8, 10, 3, 3]

print(np.diff(np.array(a)))
```

> [-2  4  2 -1  1  1  2 -7  0]

**UPDATE**

```
import numpy as np

a = [3, 1, 5, 7, 6, 7, 8, 10, 3, 3]
b = [11, 15, 17, 86, 11, 67, 31, 56, 3, 11]
c = [12.1, 98.2, 31.6, 24.7, 12.1, 34.1, 1.8, 65.1, 22.9, 31.6]


arr_delta = [np.diff(np.array(x)).tolist() for x in (a, b, c)]
print(arr_delta)
```

Получим:

```
[[-2, 4, 2, -1, 1, 1, 2, -7, 0], [4, 2, 69, -75, 56, -36, 25, -53, 8], [86.10000000000001, -66.6, -6.900000000000002, -12.6, 22.0, -32.300000000000004, 63.3, -42.199999999999996, 8.700000000000003]]
```

Соответственно, arr_delta[0] будет:

```
[-2, 4, 2, -1, 1, 1, 2, -7, 0]
```

Либо, еще короче:

```
arr = np.array([a, b, c])
arr_delta = [np.diff(x).tolist() for x in arr]
print(arr_delta)
```

Но в этом случае обратите внимание на приведение типов.

Comment: вместо `arr_delta = arr ?`  написать получается  `print(np.diff(arr))`

Comment: дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

a = [3, 1, 5, 7, 6, 7, 8, 10, 3, 3]
b = [11, 15, 17, 86, 11, 67, 31, 56, 3, 11]
c = [12.1, 98.2, 31.6, 24.7, 12.1, 34.1, 1.8, 65.1, 22.9, 31.6]

arr = np.array([a, b, c])
res = np.array(
  [arr[0][:-1]-arr[0][1:],
  arr[1][:-1]-arr[1][1:], 
  arr[2][:-1]-arr[2][1:]]
)
    
[[  2.   -4.   -2.    1.   -1.   -1.   -2.    7.    0. ]
 [ -4.   -2.  -69.   75.  -56.   36.  -25.   53.   -8. ]
 [-86.1  66.6   6.9  12.6 -22.   32.3 -63.3  42.2  -8.7]]
```

Comment: а если с тремя  , то как реализовать?

Comment: поправил на 3 немного не красиво конечно, вариант с diff мне больше нравится я не знал про него

Comment: в моем случае правда не вылазят нули, если это как-то важно вообще) не знаю откуда они появляются с diff

Comment: В вашем случае полностью нивелируется функционал `numpy`, вы совершенно теряете эффективность. а нули появляются из-за type coercion.

Comment: я же признал что мой вариант не самый красивый) в то же время вычитание массивов не нивелируют numpy - это его функционал

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.diff` считает то что нужно (называется [конечная разность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)). Передайте  параметр `axis` чтобы указать вдоль какой оси считать разности:

```
import numpy as np

a = [3, 1, 5, 7, 6, 7, 8, 10, 3, 3]
b = [11, 15, 17, 86, 11, 67, 31, 56, 3, 11]
c = [12.1, 98.2, 31.6, 24.7, 12.1, 34.1, 1.8, 65.1, 22.9, 31.6]
 
arr = np.array([a, b, c])
 
arr_delta = np.diff(arr, axis=1)

print(arr_delta)
```

> ```
> [[ -2.    4.    2.   -1.    1.    1.    2.   -7.    0. ]
>  [  4.    2.   69.  -75.   56.  -36.   25.  -53.    8. ]
>  [ 86.1 -66.6  -6.9 -12.6  22.  -32.3  63.3 -42.2   8.7]]
> ```